# Bad file descriptor message when creating compressed file with gzip.exe on Windows, using Visual FoxPro9 and WINAPI functions

Tags: winapi, visual-foxpro

What i'm trying to do is write text to gzip.exe StdIn and redirect its StdOut to a file, all this using WINAPI functions and visual Foxpro 9.

The problem is that I always get "*Stdin: Bad file descriptor*" error and no output. What I expect to have is the file associated with StdOut filled with data and the file associated with StdErr empty. Instead I always endup with the file associated with StdOut empty and the file associated with StdErr filled with:

> standard input: Bad file descriptor gzip:"

Here is my code:

```
*----------------------------------------------------------------


LOCAL cBuffer, nBytesRead, newBufSize, nBytesWritten

LOCAL hReadPipe, hWritePipe, res, cSecAttr, cFile, hFile, process_info, start_info, hProcess, hThread

*---------------------------------------------------

#DEFINE BUFF_SIZE 1024

#DEFINE WAIT_TIMEOUT 0x00000102

#DEFINE WAIT_INTERVAL 5000

#DEFINE INFINITE 0xFFFFFFFF

*---------------------------------------------------

#DEFINE HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT 0x00000001
*---------------------------------------------------

#DEFINE FILE_APPEND_DATA 4

#DEFINE FILE_SHARE_READ 0x00000001

#DEFINE FILE_SHARE_WRITE 0x00000002

#DEFINE CREATE_ALWAYS 2

#DEFINE FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL 0x80

#DEFINE INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE -1

#DEFINE GENERIC_READ 0x80000000

#DEFINE GENERIC_WRITE 0x40000000

*---------------------------------------------------

#DEFINE STARTF_USESTDHANDLES 0x00000100

#DEFINE STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW 0x00000001

#DEFINE CREATE_NO_WINDOW 0x08000000

*---------------------------------------------------

DECLARE INTEGER WaitForSingleObject IN kernel32.DLL ;

             INTEGER hHandle, ;

             INTEGER dwMilliseconds 
DECLARE INTEGER GetLastError IN kernel32.DLL

DECLARE INTEGER CloseHandle IN kernel32.DLL INTEGER hObject

DECLARE INTEGER CreatePipe IN kernel32;

             INTEGER @ hReadPipe, ;

             INTEGER @ hWritePipe, ;

              STRING @ lpPipeAttributes, ;

                LONG   nSize 
DECLARE INTEGER SetHandleInformation IN Kernel32 ;

             INTEGER hObject, ;

                LONG dwMask, ;

                LONG dwFlags 
DECLARE INTEGER ReadFile IN kernel32 ;

             INTEGER   hFile, ;

              STRING @ lpBuffer, ;

             INTEGER   nNumberOfBytesToRead, ;


             INTEGER @ lpNumberOfBytesRead, ;

             INTEGER   lpOverlapped 
DECLARE INTEGER WriteFile IN Kernel32 ;

             INTEGER hFile, ;

             STRING lpBuffer, ;

             INTEGER nBt2Write, ;

             INTEGER @ lpBtWritten, ;

             INTEGER lpOverlapped  
DECLARE INTEGER CreateFile IN Kernel32.DLL ;

             STRING lpFileName, ;

            INTEGER dwDesiredAccess, ;

            INTEGER dwShareMode, ; 

             STRING lpSecurityAttributes, ;

            INTEGER dwCreationDisposition, ;

            INTEGER dwFlagsAndAttributes, ;

            INTEGER hTemplateFile 
DECLARE INTEGER CreateProcess IN kernel32.DLL ;

            INTEGER lpApplicationName, ;

             STRING lpCommandLine, ;

            INTEGER lpProcessAttributes, ;

            INTEGER lpThreadAttributes, ;

            INTEGER bInheritHandles, ;

            INTEGER dwCreationFlags, ;

            INTEGER lpEnvironment, ;

            INTEGER lpCurrentDirectory, ;

             STRING @lpStartupInfo, ;

             STRING @lpProcessInformation  
*-------------------------------------------------------

hReadPipe=0

hWritePipe=0

cSecAttr=BINTOC(12,'4RS')+BINTOC(0,'4RS')+BINTOC(1,'4RS')

res=CreatePipe(@hReadPipe,@hWritePipe,cSecAttr,BUFF_SIZE)

res=SetHandleInformation(hReadPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,0)

res=SetHandleInformation(hWritePipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,0)

*-------------------------------------------------------

cSecAttr=BINTOC(12,'4RS')+BINTOC(0,'4RS')+BINTOC(1,'4RS')

cFile="d:\ggzz.sql.gz"

hFile=0
hFile=CreateFile(cFile,BITOR(GENERIC_READ,GENERIC_WRITE),BITOR(FILE_SHARE_READ,FILE_SHARE_WRITE),cSecAttr,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0)

*-------------------------------------------------------

cSecAttr=BINTOC(12,'4RS')+BINTOC(0,'4RS')+BINTOC(1,'4RS')

cFile="d:\gzip.err"

hGzipErr=0

hGzipErr=CreateFile(cFile,BITOR(GENERIC_READ,GENERIC_WRITE),BITOR(FILE_SHARE_READ,FILE_SHARE_WRITE),cSecAttr,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0)

*-------------------------------------------------------

cKmd="d:\gzip\bin\gzip.exe"

process_info = REPLICATE(CHR(0), 16)

start_info = BINTOC(68,'4RS') + REPLICATE(CHR(0), 64) start_info=LEFT(start_info,44)+BINTOC(BITOR(STARTF_USESTDHANDLES,STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW),'4RS')+REPLICATE(CHR(0), 20)

start_info=LEFT(start_info,56)+BINTOC(hReadPipe,'4RS')+BINTOC(hFile,'4RS')+BINTOC(hGzipErr,'4RS')

res = CreateProcess(0,cKmd, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, @start_info, @process_info)

hProcess=CTOBIN(SUBSTR(process_info, 1, 4),'4RS')

hThread=CTOBIN(SUBSTR(process_info, 5, 4),'4RS')

DIMENSION aaa(3)

aaa(1)="11111111111111111111111"

aaa(2)="222222222222222222222222"

aaa(3)="3333333333333333333333"

FOR i=1 TO ALEN(aaa)

  cBuffer=aaa(i)

  newBufsize=LEN(cBuffer)

  nBytesWritten=0

  res=WriteFile(hWritePipe,cBuffer,newBufsize,@nBytesWritten,0)

  IF nBytesWritten=0

     EXIT 

  ENDIF 
ENDFOR

=WaitForSingleObject(hProcess,INFINITE)

res=CloseHandle(hFile)

res=CloseHandle(hThread)

res=CloseHandle(hProcess)

res=CloseHandle(hReadPipe)

res=CloseHandle(hWritePipe)

CLEAR DLLS "CreatePipe","GetLastError", "CreateFile", "CreateProcess", "CloseHandle","SetHandleInformation", ; "ReadFile", "WriteFile"
```

Comment: There is no error checking anywhere, you should add some to check the results of the API calls and identify specifically what is failing.

Comment: I removed error checking so that the code be more readable. In fact no errors were reported WINAPI getLastError() reports 0 in all lines. All "res" variables are 0 except after CreateFile() it reports  183 which in fact is not an error just the file is recreated if it already exists. Maybe I  I'm being wrong with the flags of WINAPI functions, I still don't finde any solution